# How can I change tabcontrol color of a button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to change the tabcontrol color. I tried it too much and I searched for it here on SO but I didn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: What similar post did you see? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Maybe do you mean the focus color?

Comment: @fuex Yes I want to change that specified color which is shown in this images, is there any property through which i can change this color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same type of problem I am also facing you can do this by changing the property **DrawMode**. change it from **Normal** to **Ownerdrawfixed**
Please visit this link too
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8289/Coloring-Tab-Control

Comment: You are right it solve the problem mean it change the color but when i change it, its hide the icons which are displaying on tab page